# How to fix a magic number in Android?

Tags: android

When I define a variable:

```
private static float rateCost3 = 3;
```

... I get a warning:

> '3' is a magic number.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 6):

A magic number is a direct usage of a number in the code. To fix this use:

```
private static final float RATE_COST_3 = 3;
```

It improves readability of the code and it's easier to maintain.

Some info here: http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceMagicNumberWithSymbolicConstant.html